# Objective-C call a method from another UIViewController, what self refers to?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uiviewcontroller, self

I have 2 UIViewControllers in a UITabBar and would like to create a facade for one of my UIViewControllers, and am running into issues when trying to do this:

```
//within the 2nd view controller, that has not been displayed yet:
-(void)startApp
{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

I'm trying

```
//within the first view controller:

[delegate startApp]
```

**What does "self" refer to in the example above?** If I set a breakpoint, I see that the callback within the 2nd view controller gets called, but it does not produce the same effect as when I call it from the 2nd view controller directly.

The ViewDidLoad within the 2nd view controller does not get called until I tap on that controller, but still, even if I do so, and then call the startApp method, the result is still unexpected.

It is very possible that I broke the MVC model with my setup, and will have to pull out pieces of code and create an underlying model that both controllers would be using, but I was hoping for a quick and dirty solution.

Thank you for any clarifications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

startApp is an instance method on "2nd View Controller", so 'self' refers to the particular instance of your "2nd View Controller" that received this message.

Comment: Thank you! The problem that I've ran into is that the UIViewController is initialized, but because the user has never selected that tab, the -viewDidLoad has never been called, which caused all sorts of issues.